# Merge multiple different changesets using command line

Tags: c#, tfs, merge, command

does anyone know the tfs command to merge baseless by specifying different changesets like C1098,C5078 etc.
I currently know the command to specify the range but not the specific changesets.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do that in one merge. You can merge (up to) a specific changeset, or you can merge a range but you cannot merge changeset 1 and changeset 5 at the same time.

I would suggest that you use the following command

`tf merge $/Myteamproject/MyBranch $/MyTeamProject/MyOtherBranch /recursive /baseless /version:C1098`

Once you have done this then a merge relationship will be created between the 2 branches. From this point you can now merge normally between the 2 branches. You can then use the command line

`tf merge $/Myteamproject/MyBranch $/MyTeamProject/MyOtherBranch /recursive /version:C5078`

or you can use Team Explorer / Visual Studio to perform any new merges that are required

Comment: Thanks that's what I thought as well. But unfortunately there is no example to show this.